# Pagerank Markov chain reductions

Tags: graph-theory, probability-distributions, algorithms, markov-chains, stochastic-matrices

---

**In short:** if a Markov chain models a (generalized) pagerank, is it always possible to remove any of its state and obtain a Markov chain that models a pagerank close to the initial one?

---

**Full details.**

Given:

- a finite directed graph $G=(V,E)$ with $E \subseteq V\times V$,
- two functions $P$ and $\alpha$ over vertices in $V$ such that $\sum_v P(v) = 1$ and $\alpha(v) \in [0,1]$ for all $v$, and
- a weight function $\omega$ over $V\times V$ such that for all $u$, $\sum_v \omega(u,v) = 1$, and $\omega(u,v) = 0$ if $(u,v) \not\in E$,

we define the ***pagerank Markov chain*** of $G$, $\omega$, $P$ and $\alpha$ by its transition matrix $M$ defined for all $u$ and $v$ in $V$ by: $M_{u,v} = \alpha(u)\cdot\omega(u,v) + (1-\alpha(u))\cdot P(v)$. Such Markov chains are generalizations of the [classical (personalized) pagerank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank).

Now let us consider any vertex $v$ in $V$, denote by $V'$ the set $V\setminus \{v\}$, and by $E'$ the set $(E \cap V'\times V') \cup \{u, (u,v)\in E\} \times \{w, (v,w)\in E\}$. In other words, the graph $G'=(V',E')$ is obtained from $G$ by removing vertex $v$ and its edges, and adding edges from its predecessors to its successors only.

---

**Question:** Is it always possible to find functions $\omega'$, $P'$, and $\alpha'$ such that the pagerank Markov chain of $G'$, $\omega'$, $P'$ and $\alpha'$ has stationary distribution proportional to the one defined above?

---

Notice that it is always possible to find a Markov chain with stationary distribution proportional to the initial one; my question is: it is always possible to find one that is a pagerank Markov chain on $G'$?

If $v$ is a *bridge node*, *i.e.* $|\{u, (u,v)\in E\}| = |\{w, (v,w)\in E\}| = 1$, then I am able to prove that the answer is positive. I use Section 3 of [the paper *Stochastic Complementation, Uncoupling Markov Chains, and the Theory of Nearly Reducible Systems* by Carl D. Meyer](https://doi.org/10.1137/1031050) to obtain the wanted Markov chain and then exhibit (quite terrible) expressions for $\omega'$, $P'$, and $\alpha'$.

The general case however seems much more complex. Maybe a better characterization of pagerank Markov chains would help finding a counter-example?

Comment: Well, if you choose $\alpha'(v) = 0$ for all vertices $v$, you can achieve any stationary distribution you would like to have by simply choosing $P'$ to be that stationary distribution. So I suspect you want to impose an additional restriction on the parameters?

Comment: @JochenGlueck You are right! Surely, I do not want to have to compute the initial stationary distribution, but being more specific is not so easy. Let me say that I want to find solutions in time and space $O(|N(v)|)$, the degree of removed vertex $v$.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I think it's not possible in general to find a solution within the time constraints that you specified; indeed, assume that it was possible. Every stochastic $d \times d$-matrix $M$ can be interpreted as a transition matrix as given in your model, and it takes $O(d^2)$ time to compute the corresponding model parameters from $M$. The number $|N(v)|$ is bounded by $d$, so we can remove vertex $1$ and build, by assumption, a $(d-1) \times (d-1)$ model in $O(d)$ time such all remaining components of the stationary distribution are the same. [...]

Comment: [...] Computing the stationary distribution of the $d \times d$-matrix when $d-1$ components are already known also takes $O(d)$ time. By iterating this argument $d-1$-times we can reduce the problem to a $1 \times 1$-situation and from this, we can thus compute the stationary distrubution of $M$ in $O(d^2)$ time; but I don't think $O(d^2)$ is possible for computation of stationary distrubtions, in general (admittedly, though, I'm not an expert in numerical mathematics).